# Unit testing the async await function in angular 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, async-await

I need to know how to write unit testing for async/await functions in angular 5 which connect with a background service for STT service .Can anybody help?

```
async listen(){
 let data = await fetch('http://localhost:13005/getGoogleText', {
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return (error);
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: which language is this? I don't think it's typescript neither is it C#? can you put the real code

Comment: @JackM why you think it is not TypeScript?

Comment: @karthikeyan, you might want to go through with few articles related to mocking the http service like https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-angular-2-http-services-with-jasmine and then come up with some code(like fiddle) if you face any issue.

Comment: @JackM It is typescript.